# Почему first-of-type и [href$=] не взаимодействуют вместе?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Есть список с позициями, которых может быть произвольное количество, но первый и последний при этом совпадают по ссылке.

Мне нужно добиться того, чтобы у первого элемента была иконка, а у последнего многоточие. Пытаюсь крутиться через *first-of-type*, *last-of-type*, [href$= ], но что-то не выходит..

Нарушать структуру `html` при этом нельзя.

```css
div a:first-of-type[href$=sdfsdf]:before {
   content: "\f19c";
   font-size: 12px;
   display: inline-block;
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
    
div a:last-of-type[href$=sdfsdf]:before {
  content: "...";
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <p><a href="/sdfsdf">List 1</a></p>
  <p><a href="/vcbcvbf">List 2</a></p>
  <p><a href="/ert">List 3</a></p>
  <p><a href="/oplll">List 4</a></p>
  <p><a href="/sdfsdf">List 5</a></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементы в вашем примере не имеют общего родителя, поэтому каждая ссылка в вашем примере является и первой и последней в своем родителе и срабатывание селектора происходит чисто по условию `[href$=sdfsdf]`

Если точно известно, что нужны именно первый и последний элементы, можно попробовать так:

```css
div p:first-of-type a[href$=sdfsdf]:before {
   content: "\f19c";
   font-size: 12px;
   display: inline-block;
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
    
div p:last-of-type a[href$=sdfsdf]:before {
  content: "...";
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <p><a href="/sdfsdf">List 1</a></p>
  <p><a href="/vcbcvbf">List 2</a></p>
  <p><a href="/ert">List 3</a></p>
  <p><a href="/oplll">List 4</a></p>
  <p><a href="/sdfsdf">List 5</a></p>
</div>
```

В целом, в таком случае, можно и фильтр `[href$=sdfsdf]` опустить.

### Уточнение

Элементы из примера, конечно, имеют общего родителя `div`, но при этом они не являются соседними (они не `siblings`).
То есть, в дереве DOMа у них есть общий родитель, но они не на одной и той же ветке, т.к. у них у каждого своя ветка `p`.